# How can I overload operators with const operands correctly?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, pass-by-reference

I'm learning C++ recently and have some basic Fraction class to implement operator overloads on. One of the operators to be overloaded is `*`.

A quick implementation for multiplying two Fraction types:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator* (const Fraction &rightOperand)
{
    return Fraction(numerator * rightOperand.numerator, denominator * rightOperand.denominator);
}
```

And one for multiplying where the right hand operand is an `int`:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator* (int rightOperand)
{
    return Fraction(numerator * rightOperand, denominator);
}
```

Then, because multiplication is commutative, multiplying where the *left* hand operator should be simply:

```
// declared as friend
Fraction operator* (int leftOperand, const Fraction &rightOperand)
{
    return rightOperand * leftOperand; // should use the overload above, right?
}
```

However, in the last function, the '*' gives an error:

> no operator "*" matches these operands -- operand types are: const Fraction * int

I set the parameters to be const references because they are not written to... is this incorrect in this case or is there some way around this? Surely I don't have to define a whole load of duplications of the member functions as global free functions with two arguments just to add `const` to the parameters?

Comment: `Fraction Fraction::operator* (const Fraction &rightOperand) const `

Comment: `const` _after_ the parameter list?! Wow, that looks odd, don't think I would ever have figured that by myself XD

Comment: [C.168 from CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c168-define-overloaded-operators-in-the-namespace-of-their-operands). You want to overload operators as (possibly `friend`) free functions most of the time

Comment: @Justin AFAICT the linked item says that overloaded operators should be defined in the same namespace as their operands... that can be the case for free or non-free functions though, no?

Comment: @Toby You may be right. I guess maybe there isn't a core guideline on that. At any rate, only a few of the operators should be overloaded as member functions. The idiom is for most binary operators to be overloaded as free functions. It helps in avoiding errors

Comment: @Toby: Which C++ book are you using? Function `const`ness is pretty fundamental.

Comment: @Toby one way of thinking about is that the binary operators create a new object, they don't modify an existing one, so there is no need for them to be member functions.

Comment: Thanks @RichardCritten, very helpful info! It could make an answer?

Comment: @Toby: mmmmm yeah you're going to need to get a book Toby. I think it's clear that our free time is not supposed to be used as a substitute for you learning the language you have agreed to work in.

Comment: Good luck though - sounds like fun!

Comment: Would rather this was closed referencing the duplicate.

Comment: @RichardCritten: While factually accurate on the surface, that logic would suggest that no `const` member function should exist, which is clearly false. As such I'm not sure that this is the best way to teach it

Comment: OK, , I'll close so :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit was only rough guidance and I said "no need" not "must".

Comment: @RichardCritten: was only a rough debunking :)

Comment: Seriously though granularity doesn't affect whether your students will heed your words - they will - so it's important not to misteach. I know you didn't mean to. You may still agree with your earlier comment even. YMMV :)